# Raspberry Pi 2 elm 327 OBD Bluetooth connection Problem

Tags: pi-2, bluetooth, raspbian-wheezy

I am using a `Raspberry Pi 2` `Wheezy` with a Bluetooth dongle to capture data from an `ELM 327 OBD`.

I can list the OBD device but I am unable to connect to that through Bluetooth. I am getting an error like:
[image: Console snapshot]

> Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Host is down

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: what bluetooth dongle are you running?

Comment: also can you please share the result of the following command `hciconfig`

Comment: Why not dist-upgrade from "wheezy" to "jessie"? This is so that you move to the current (Raspbian 8.x) version - and given that Raspbian tracks the upstream Debian distribution we'll get "Stretch" (9.0) sometime soon: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=186300

Comment: +1 for upgrading to Jessie as Wheezy is no longer receiving updates.

Answer (score 1):

This was tested is Jessie rather than wheezy but should still work. See image below for an example but type:

```
$sudo systemctl start bluetooth
$sudo bluetoothctl
#power on
#agent on
#scan on
#trust MAC_ADDRESS
#exit
$sudo rfcomm connect 0 MAC_ADDRESS 1
```

I have obscured MAC addresses and device names because it is a client's device.

[image]

Comment: We also got the same in Jessie but need to implement the same in Wheezy.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any experience with Wheezy and I don't have time to set up a Pi with it on. I would suggest looking at any Bluetooth tutorials which pre-date Jessie's release (Approx September 2015) such as [this one](https://www.modmypi.com/blog/installing-the-raspberry-pi-nano-bluetooth-dongle) to see if they do anything similar to what you're tying to do. If you could post some information on what dongle you are using and what steps you have already tried that might help other users as well.

Comment: Also when you try my answer in Wheezy does the bluetoothctl work or does it give any error messages?